# How can I improve on peach by using the scan adverb?

Tags: kdb

I have a list of times, and I want to count how many are within a given time window from each time. i.e. for each time, how many of the following times are less than 10 minutes ahead.

This is what I have so far, and it works well for small lists, ts<10000, but even using peach, it struggles when the count is above this, and get wsfull errors.

```
q)ts:asc `time$10?10000000
q)ts where each {(x<=y) and (y<x+00:10)}[;ts] peach ts
00:10:20.526 00:11:41.084 00:15:59.360 00:20:15.625
00:11:41.084 00:15:59.360 00:20:15.625
00:15:59.360 00:20:15.625
,00:20:15.625
,01:11:14.831
02:14:36.999 02:17:47.700
02:17:47.700 02:25:44.267 02:27:02.389
02:25:44.267 02:27:02.389 02:28:16.790
02:27:02.389 02:28:16.790
,02:28:16.790
```

I have tried using scan and over, but can't figure out how to stop the iteration when I need to.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - If its just the count you're after then all you need is:

```
q)1+(ts bin ts+00:10)-til count ts
1 3 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1
```

OLD ANSWER - If you're trying to actually generate the list of times (not sure why you need to do that) then no matter what you do you're going to end up eating up a good bit of memory (generating a large list of potentially large lists of times). Also peach may not be useful since the time gained in outsourcing to other threads might be undone by the time needed to send the result back to the main thread. And any form of iteration/loop is likely to be slow since it will be acting atomically

Having said that, the best solution would be to make use of bin, especially if your list is sorted. For example, either of these two should give you the list of times and they scale a bit better (again, you shouldn't need to generate the lists if you're just using them to count - see edit above):

```
ts t+til each 1+(ts bin ts+00:10)-t:til count ts

{y[1]#y[0]_x}[ts] each t,'1+(ts bin ts+00:10)-t:til count ts
```

but they still involve generating lists of lists of indices and they will still add up.

Note that the bin (which is giving the index of the last item within 10mins of each item) is incredibly fast and memory efficient, even if the list is in the tens of millions:

```
q)ts:asc `time$10000000?10000000
q)
q)\ts ts bin ts+00:10
160 201326768
```